# Dynamic tone for notification in android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to set dynamic voice tone for notification, when I will get the notification from different contact person(like set incoming call ringtone to specific contact person). For example, my friend Robert send me a message, that time I want to hear the notification tone as “Hi, I'm Robert”. Suppose my another friend Peter  send a message, that time I want to hear the notification tone as”Hi, I'm Peter”. Like this I want to hear dynamic notification tone regarding each person. Is it possible to do in android through programmatically? If possible please help me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

TextToSpeech ==> You need to set up T2S engine as a feedback system with your notification ===> First up create the text that you want to be read out as a string==> Pass that String to TextToSpeech Engine of Android on the onReceive of the broadcast receiver.

Comment: No I want to set the recorded voice as notification tone. I don't want to use TextToSpeech concept.For example, if you send some message that time I will get notification, I want to hear one tone. Suppose another one message me that time I want to hear another tone which I have already assigned to that person.

Comment: it cannot get more BRIEF.
First up create the text that you want to be read out as a string, then try to implement TextToSpeech object in a separate project. It should work fine!